# How do you create a int buffer in python with ctypes

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory

I am trying to write to memory in python. I need to write an Integer but for the WriteProcessMemory function, I need a buffer.

```
writeProcessMemory = kernel.WriteProcessMemory
writeProcessMemory.argtypes = [ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE, 
ctypes.wintypes.LPVOID, ctypes.wintypes.LPCVOID, ctypes.c_size_t, 
                         ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_size_t)]
writeProcessMemory.restype = ctypes.wintypes.BOOL


openProcess = kernel.OpenProcess
openProcess.argtypes = [ctypes.wintypes.DWORD, ctypes.wintypes.BOOL, 
ctypes.wintypes.DWORD]
openProcess.restype = ctypes.wintypes.HANDLE

handle = openProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, pid)
addr = 0x024EA498
data = ctypes.c_int(1000)
buffer = #i need to create a buffer here
```

Comment: create a char buffer with the size multiplied by the size of int in C. Careful as int size isn't normalized

Comment: But won't that write a char to memory? sorry if this is a dumb question im just trying to understand it

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`create_string_buffer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.create_string_buffer)

```
buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b"",1000 * 4)
```

to create a 0-filled buffer of 1000 4-size integers. This buffer is of type `ctypes.c_char_Array_4000` that can be passed as a pointer to write into to imported functions.

> This function creates a mutable character buffer. The returned object is a ctypes array of c_char.
>
> init_or_size must be an integer which specifies the size of the array, or a bytes object which will be used to initialize the array items.
>
> If a bytes object is specified as first argument, the buffer is made one item larger than its length so that the last element in the array is a NUL termination character. An integer can be passed as second argument which allows specifying the size of the array if the length of the bytes should not be used.

Now call your imported function, and get the python `bytes` object just written by using:

```
python_bytes_array = ctypes.string_at(buffer)
```

**Note**: `ctypes.string_at(address, size=-1)` If size is specified, it is used as size, otherwise the string is assumed to be zero-terminated. [ctypes docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)

and use `struct` to get hold of the integer values. No need to specify the endianness. `I` is 4 bytes. It will work if called functions use 4-byte integers:

```
import struct
integer_tuple = struct.unpack("1000I",python_bytes_array)
```

Comment: If you open an interactive console, ```import ctypes``` ```import struct``` and run those 3 lines of code you get ```struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4000 bytes``` using ```python 3.8.6```